iOS application to Go application synchronization
I have a project that involves running Tasks, where each task is a routine run in a Go application on a computer. The Go computer application (Supports Linux, Windows, Mac) gives users the option to:

create Tasks
Start tasks that have been created
View running tasks

Currently each task is stored on a .csv file on the computer. Users that downloads this computer exe will also be able to download a mobile iOS application. This iOS app should also give users the same 3 features as above. But the Go computer application is the only one that actually runs these tasks.
I will be using Google Firebase to store information. What is the best way to Sync a Go exe and a iOS application?
My first thought

Store tasks in a "task" collection. Setup a snapshot listener on the iOS app and another in the Go app. This will listen to new/deleted/updates tasks.
Create a "Start task" document (both ends listen to this document), the iOS app writes the name of the task to start onto a queue in this document. When the Go app sees the new write, it starts the task, then deletes the entry in the queue.

